# Error "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint " using Identity with custom property and relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

---

I'm very new to asp.net MVC and I'm practicing building this application.

I'm trying to add a custom property to the default IdentityModel.cs generated by visual studio. This customproperty will held the university library that an user belongs to.

I'm sorry if I made this post too large, but I really don't know what is causing the problem and what should I omit.

What I have made so far:
Created the University library entity:

```
 public class UniversityLibrary
{
    [Key]
    public int UniversityLibraryId { get; set; }
    public string UniversityLibraryName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users {get;set;}

}
```

Added the custom property to IdentityModel.cs:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

public virtual UniversityLibrary UniversityLibraries { get; set; }  
public int UniversityLibraryId { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }


}
```

Added the custom property in the RegisterViewModel:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{


    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("University Library ID")]
    public int UniversityLibraryId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UniversityLibrary> Libraries { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Created a list of University libraries to be passed to my view using actionfilter:

```
public class ViewbagListOfUniversityLibraries : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        IncludeRoleListIntoViewBag(filterContext.Controller.ViewBag);
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }

    private void IncludeRoleListIntoViewBag(dynamic viewBag)
    {
        using (var db = new LibraryManagementWebAppContext())
        {
            viewBag.UniversityLibraryList = db.UniversityLibraries
                .OrderBy(x => x.UniversityLibraryName)
                .Select(unversityLibrary => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = unversityLibrary.UniversityLibraryName,
                    Value = unversityLibrary.UniversityLibraryId.ToString()
                })
                .ToList();

        }
    }
}
```

Modified the Register view to add the dropdown of university libraries:

```
@model LibraryManagementWebApp.Models.RegisterViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> universityLibraryList = ViewBag.UniversityLibraryList;
}
...
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UniversityLibraryId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UniversityLibraryId, universityLibraryList,"Select One", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Added modelbuilders to my other context (the context for university Libraries), because it was causing erros like "EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType"

```
public class LibraryManagementWebAppContext : DbContext
{
   public LibraryManagementWebAppContext() : base("name=LibraryManagementWebAppContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UniversityLibrary> UniversityLibraries { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<UniversityLibrary>().HasKey(r => r.UniversityLibraryId);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

Modified the controller to get the selected value before creating the new user in my database:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ViewbagListOfUniversityLibraries]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, UniversityLibraryId = Convert.ToInt32(model.UniversityLibraryId) };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

The problem is:
When i try to register a new user, a get this error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.AspNetUsers_dbo.UniversityLibraries_UniversityLibraryId". The conflict occurred in database "ASPNET_LIBRARYMANAGEMENTWEBAPP_aa38b17e20d0416d8c53a3a5d0faa59e", table "dbo.UniversityLibraries", column 'UniversityLibraryId'.
```

And I dont know how to solve it.
Debugging my code I can see my user variable have a value for UniversityLibraryId.
[Debugging: user variable that is passed to CreateAsync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB5R5.png)

Also already verified in the database and UniversityLibrary table have the item with this same id.
[checked the database to see if the data is there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfECS.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to find what I was doing wrong...

As I have two contexts (One auto generated "IdentityModel.cs" and the second that I generated following this tutorial [creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application))

Each context was pointing to a different database, both with the same tables.

So I was sucesfully creting "university libraries" to be used in the register page, but they we being created in the wrong database.

Then I made some changes to make both contexts point to the same database and made my LibraryManagementWebAppContext inherit from  IdentityDbContext

My context for University libraries:

```
public class LibraryManagementWebAppContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
   public LibraryManagementWebAppContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UniversityLibrary> UniversityLibraries { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
 
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(l => l.UserId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasKey(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<UniversityLibrary>().HasKey(r => r.UniversityLibraryId);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    
}
```

And the default IdentityModel generated by visual studio:

```
 public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

   
}
```

After that I droped the databases and could sucesfully:
1 - Create University libraries
2 - Register user using my list of University Libraries

As I said before, I am very new to asp.NET, so probably I did something that even working isn't the best aproach.
Please feel free to complement my answer or sugest something that could be done.

Thank you.